# Using socket io to get data realtime not working

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, socket.io, mean-stack

I'm new to mean-stack and I followed some instruction on how to get real-time data. I tried every single steps but none of it is working, how can I use socket.io correctly? I provided my code here for getting users from mongodb, please do correct my code

**server.js**

```
var express     = require ('express');
var app         = express();
var server      = require('http').Server(app);
var http        = require('http').Server(app);
var io          = require('socket.io')(http);
var morgan      = require ('morgan');
var mongoose    = require('mongoose');
var appRoutes   = require('./app/routes/api');

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use('/api',appRoutes);

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/testing', function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log('Not connected' + err);
    } else
    {
        console.log('Connected');
    }
});
```

Then here is the part where I get the users from the table, I don't know how to get the the data real-time:

**api.js**

```
var User = require('../models/user');
const router = express.Router();
router.get('/management', function(req, res) {
        User.find({}, function(err, users) {
                if (!users) {
                    res.json({ success: false, message: 'Users not found' }); 
                } else {
                    res.json({ success: true, users: users,});
                }
        });
    });
```

**userCtrl.js**

```
.controller('managementCtrl', function(User, $scope) {
 function getUsers() { 
        User.getUsers().then(function(data) {
            if (data.data.success) {
                app.users = data.data.users;    
            } else {
                app.errorMsg = data.data.message; 
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**users.html**

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="person in management.users">
        <td align="center">{{ person.name }}</td>
        <td align="center">{{ person.email }}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to get a socket with `connection` event:

```js
io.on('connect', function(socket){
```

than you need to set a "listener" on specific event you want to reply with data

Together it will be:

```js
io.on('connect', function(socket){
    socket.on('eventYouGet', function(eventData) {
        User.find({}, function(err, users) {
            if (!users) {
                socket.emit('eventAnswer', {success: false, message: 'Users not found'});
            } else {
                socket.emit('eventAnswer', {success: true, users: users)};
           }
        });
    });
});
```

Where `eventYouGet` is event which you (from server perspective) are waiting for (kind of like request in REST); `eventAnswer` is event you send as answer (to the client).

Note:
`socket.emit` sends an event to sender and no one else (one socket)

Answer (score 0):

On the server - 
I generally check for connections:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');
});
```

You'll need for the client and the server to agree on some sort of token to listen to for socket. In this case, I am hardcoding in '123123123'

```
var User = require('../models/user');
    const router = express.Router();
    router.get('/management', function(req, res) {
            User.find({}, function(err, users) {
                    if (!users) {
                        io.emit("123123123", { success: false, message: 'Users not found' });
                    } else {
                        io.emit("123123123", { success: true, users: users,});
                    }
            });
        });
```

In angular -

```
var socket = io.connect(<url>); //url from server
socket.on('123123123', function (user) {  
    let user = json.parse(user)        
});
```